# Allow access to a certain page on a site, only if they come from a link on another certain page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For my ASP.NET MVC website, I want to allow access to a certain page, *only* if the user comes from a link on another certain page (that page could be from completely different URL).

Example:

I want to allow a user access to **www.MySite.com/thispage**, *only* if they come from a link on **www.MySite.com/thatpage** or **www.MyOtherSite.com/thatpage**

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Don't do this if you intend for it to be *secure*.  The http_referrer can be manually set without actually having been to the previous page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to check the [HTTP_REFERER](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) header

You can do that with

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

That said, this isn't **real** security. Someone could set the referer header of their browser manually.

If this is just a means of preventing hotlinking, it's fine. But if you're only using this to keep people out of private/secure information, you'll want to implement some real form of authentication/authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict it with the Referer however this can easily be manipulated so if this is very important to you... I would go another route.

What you can do is use .htaccess to prevent the incoming referring link from reaching your site. You could deny the incoming traffic from the site or link in question completely. Or, maybe you simply redirect or forward the incoming traffic from the site or link to somewhere else.

This can be applied to any web site with .htaccess as long as your host has mod_rewrite enabled.

If you are using Dolphin and it is installed in your root/main/http docs/public_html directory then you would add to:
yoursite()com/.htaccess

If you are using Dolphin and it is installed in a subfolder/subdirectory then you would add to:
yoursite()com/dolphin-directory/.htaccess

Add to .htaccess file after the line RewriteEngine on like:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} baddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

To forward or redirect traffic from the unwanted site or link to somewhere else then add:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} baddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://en.wikipedia.org/ [R,L]

Note:
-Change RewriteCond line: baddomain.com to the link or site you want to prevent.
-Change RewriteRule line: http://en.wikipedia.org/ to the link or site you would like to redirect or forward it to.

--Be sure to download and backup your original .htaccess file prior to editing it. Htaccess is extremely sensitive and needs to be exactly right, or it can make your entire site error out.

---And be sure you test afterward to ensure everything is working properly. You do not want to accidentally block all traffic to your site.

---

You could always track what sites they visit like the big agencies do thus block them if they aren't coming from your utopia :)