# Redirecting traffic from a certain URL to a certain page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Happy Friday!

I'm trying to create a redirect via .htaccess, basically when a user visits our old support system, it will send them to the IP of the new support system... Via HTACCESS I created the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} oldsystem.domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* http://newsystem.domain.com/pages/wiki-has-moved/ [R,L]
```

However, this fails to point the user from the homepage of the new system.... Please could someone help me achieve this redirect?

Note - I followed this question, but the results aren't working with the redirect from .htaccess:
[Allow access to a certain page on a site, only if they come from a link on another certain page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690619/allow-access-to-a-certain-page-on-a-site-only-if-they-come-from-a-link-on-anoth)

Note 2 -
The systems are on two separate servers, both with different IP's. However, they DO use the same domain oldsystem1.domain.com & newsystem1.domain.com.

Note 3- 
We still want users to be able to access the old content (staff members) but non staff members will be redirected to the new system. This is why we have had to point the redirect to an IP.

Comment: Why are you checking the referrer? Sounds like you should rather check the host name of the request. // This question lacks detail. Like, are the two sites hosted on the same web server under the same IP, or are they different system altogether?

Comment: @Cbroe - They are on different systems entirely (two different IP's). I assume checking against the host name, would work for this? (I'll update the question - it's not very detailed, as you rightly pointed out - thank you :) )

Comment: If they are on different systems, then you don’t need to do any additional checks - just put the code that does the redirecting “on” the old system, where the request for oldsystem1.domain.com are processed.

Comment: @CBroe - we still want internal staff to be able to access the old system for training material etc. So only outside visitors will be redirected (which is why we can only point at the IP)

Comment: @Cbroe - I've cleared the question up a bit to make more useful sense of what is the intention and reasons behind the redirect :) Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Then you simply add an exception for requests coming from your internal IP address(es) via a RewriteCond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to overcome the issue:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wiki.volocommerce.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hub.volocommerce.com/pages/wiki-has-moved/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wiki.esellerpro.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hub.volocommerce.com/pages/wiki-has-moved/ [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps anyone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the rewrite engine? Your htaccess should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1.2.3.4 . // replace with allowed ip address
RewriteRule .* http://newsystem.domain.com/pages/wiki-has-moved/ [R,L]
```

If it should be a permanent redirect add this  [L,R=301] instead of [R,L], so the browser will keep the redirect in cache and directly switch to the new site without getting redirected again.

If you want to allow multiple ip addresses you can add multiple conditions like:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1.2.3.4 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^5.6.7.8
```